# X-Editable Rails Dropdown Boolean Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, x-editable

I'm using X-Editable to change a boolean value. Currently the dropdown gives two options, "Yes" and "No", however I would like to change that to "Active" and "Inactive".

```
<%= editable user, :active %>
```

I've tried to add the options like this:

```
<%= editable user, :active, [['Active', true], ['Inactive', false]] %>
```

However that throws the following NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `each_pair' for [["Active", true], ["Inactive", false]]:Array
Did you mean?  each_slice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change your view code to this:

```
<%= editable user, :active, source: ['Active', 'Inactive'] %>
```

as mentioned in [github](https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails#making-things-editable):

```
source = [ "Active", "Disabled" ]
editable @model, :enabled, source: source
```

## Optional

The best way to this is in respect to *DRY* also proposed in [github](https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails#dont-repeat-yourself-templates)